# How to add secondary title in NSSharingServicePicker?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I've tried to implement NSSharingServicePicker with custom title, subtitle and Preview image. But unable to set custom subtitle.

[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF4gB.png)

My code,

```
let picker = NSSharingServicePicker(items: ["The Fault in Our Stars \n John Green"])
picker.delegate = something
picker.show(relativeTo: .zero, of: nsView, preferredEdge: .minY)
```